# Magento 2.2: Add Customer Attribute to Custom Tab in Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, adminhtml, customer-attribute, tabs

I'm trying to a add some custom attributes to a custom tab I created in the Customer Admin page.  I've created the custom tab with the following code:

`Vendor\MyModule\view\adminhtml\layout\customer_index_edit.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
      <block class="Vendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Branding" name="customer_edit_tab_branding">
        <action method="setTabLabel">
          <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Branding Information</argument>
        </action>
      </block>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

`Vendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Branding.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabWrapper;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;

class Branding extends TabWrapper implements TabInterface
{
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can see my custom tab in the customer admin page, but now would like to add some custom editable attributes to this tab.

[image]